# Prevention against De-Auth Attack for Handshake Capturing

Tags: wifi, wireless, aircrack-ng

As far as I know about De-authentication attack, the attacker sends de-auth packets to both router and the victim asking the victim to disconnect and reconnect. But I wonder what would happen if I disable the auto-connect.

As per my knowledge, I would be disconnected and would not reconnect. The attacker might just stop the listening after a while as the handshake was not captured, if he/she is a script kiddie.

PS: I know it's advisable to keep a strong password which cannot be found in a dictionary. But I'm curious to know if my idea would work or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would most certainly work, and rob whoever is doing it of both handshake and 'for-the-lulz'.

You can disable it on most platforms - I am not so sure about Android.

If you are interested in keeping things separate, get a pcengines alix/apu or soekris, connect wan to port1, lan to port2, and wlan on port3. don't let lan and wlan interact, restrict wlan to what you need.

Both PFSense (browser 'GUI' setup) and OpenBSD are straightforward and well-documented.

Edit: pfSense works much more reliably as an AP than OpenBSD. Using the latter, you would have to use the exact right minipci card. The rum driver (a USB dongle) for example creates an annoying kernel panic after a while in HostAP mode.

Trivia: Using WPA enterprise you can prevent anyone without the cert from connecting to your wifi. They could still sniff a bit, but most important stuff uses HTTPS/similar now, and the attacker cannot use MitM like sslstrip2/dnsproxy against your clients.